# How to match half URL using switch case for dynamic page title in php?

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I want to match URL in switch case for dynamic pages. But i am not able to print variable value in switch case.

here is my html title code in header:

```
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
```

and this is php:

```
    $name=$_GET['id'];
    switch ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
        case "/web/index.php":
            $pageTitle = 'Home';
        break;
        case "/web/new_doc.php":
            $pageTitle = 'Document';
        break;
        case "/web/new_provider.php":
            $pageTitle = 'Provider';
        break;
        case "/web/read.php?id=$name":
            $pageTitle = 'Reader';
        break;      
        default:
            $pageTitle ='Page';
```

i want to match URL like this:

```
  read.php?id=amazon prime
  book.php?id[]=A Wasted Hour&id[]=20
```

is there any way that i can match half part of URL in switch case like
      read.php?id= instead of full URL.

Comment: why don't you compare with id only ?

Comment: i solved my problem used if else instead of switch case.

Comment: @vinay Please explain the logic here.  Why doesn't `read` have a file extension like the other script names?  Do you specifically need to verify that there is an `id` value in the querystring on `read` page loads?  I would like to show you an alternative way of handling this task, but I require your clarifications first.

Comment: read.php shows information related to 'id'. so i want to show title and meta tags according to 'id'. currently i am using if-else instead of which is working fine for me. i will post solution currently i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header HTML:

```
      <head>
             <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
      </head>
```

php code:

```
    $page=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

    if($page=='/index.php')
    {
    $page_title = 'Home';

    }elseif($page=='/read.php')
    {
    $name=$_GET['id'];
    $page_title= 'Welcome '.$name;
    }elseif($page=='/searchpag.php')
    {   
    $page_title= 'Searchpage';
    }
```