# How to get data from a php array and add it inside the page title attribute using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use jquery so i can add dynamically the "store_name" data of the code bellow inside the page title attribute for seo purposes.

```
<?php 
$store_info=array(   
'store_id'=>$store_id ,
'phone'=>$data['phone'],
'store_name'=>$data['store_name'],
);
?>
```

I already tried to use this code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
$(function(){
$(document).attr('title', $data['store_name']);
});
</script>
```

but didn't work at all. What in the world i'm doing wrong ?

People mentioned that already there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready)  but this isn't what i 'm looking for. In my question i want to pass in the title attribute, data from a php array as i described above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to change title of document during .ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready)

Comment: It's not the same. In my question the problem is that i cant get and display inside the title attribute some data from a php array. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `$data['store_name']` and not `$store_info['store_name']`  ?

Comment: Nope there isnt any important reason but i already tried to use $store_info['store_name'] and didn't work either. However if i use it anywhere in the page it work fine and i can get the store name except of adding it to the title attribute of the page !!!

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960780/how-to-match-half-url-using-switch-case-for-dynamic-page-title-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a moment to figure this out, and then it hit me:

Remove the `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"` inside your script tag, since that's ignoring everything inside the tag itself. You'll then need two script tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<?php
    $store_info['store_name'] = 'new_title';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.
        '$(function(){$(document).attr("title", "' . 
        $store_info['store_name'] . 
        '" );});</script>'
?>
```

From the [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1) docs:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tomasz Foster but didnt work. I checked the console and i caught the error "ReferenceError: $data is not defined" How is this possible? Anywhere in the page i use <?php echo $data['store_name']; ?> i am getting the name of the store with out problem.

Comment: Right, sorry, use your `$store_info['store_name'];` instead of the `$data` variable. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: Same results with $store_info['store_name']   :(( I test the code inside the whole page and works fine but when i use it inside the jquery it gives "ReferenceError: $store_info is not defined"   !!!! Very frustrating :(

Comment: Agh, duh. You'll have to output the php variable, not treat it as a javascript variable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfect. You were very helpful @Tomasz Foster.